# writing the homotopy between $g\circ f$ and $g \circ h.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am trying to solve prove this problem:

Show that if $f \simeq h,$ then $g \circ f \simeq g \circ h.$

**Here is my trial:**

Suppose that $f,h: X \to Y$ are homotopic, and suppose that we have the map $g:Y \to Z.$ Let $H : X \times I \to Y$ be the homotopy from $f$ to $h.$ Define $F: X \times I \to Z$ by $F(x,t) = H (f(x), t),$ then $F(x,0) = H (f(x), 0) = g \circ f.$ And $F(x,1) = H (f(x), 1) = g \circ h.$

**My questions are:**

1- Is the expression $H (f(x), t)$ acceptable? what bothers me is that $f(x) \in Y.$

2- How can I correct my proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems you messed the order up. Indeed, $H(f(x),t)$ does not make sense as $H$ is defined on $X\times I$, but $f(x)\in Y$. You have a homotopy between maps from $X$ to $Y$ and *then* you want to go from $Y$ to $Z$. Try having your order of operations reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work. Since $f(x)\in Y$, $H(f(x),t)$ is not defined. Take
$$F(x,t)= g(H(x,t)).$$

Comment: What if I wanted to prove $f \circ g \simeq h \circ g$ instead?

Comment: @Brain In this case you need a map $g : Z \to X$. Then you can define $F(z,t) = H(g(z),t)$.

Comment: Please keep in mind: Asking additional questions in comments to answers to the main question is a bad use of the site (for example, you have already posted this extra question two times as a comment to two different answers). If you really need to ask this question, it is much better to make a new post.

Comment: @LeeMosher sorry about that, I will be careful later.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the $F$ you considered, which cannot be defined as you did (for your question 1), consider $F:X\times I\rightarrow Z,\,F(x,t)=(g\circ H)(x,t)$.
Then, $F(x,0)=(g\circ H)(x,0)=(g\circ f)(x),\,F(x,1)=(g\circ H)(x,1)=(g\circ h)(x)$. Observe that $F$ is continuous because composition of continuous maps.